# Trouble using indexOf with list of drawable resources

Tags: java, android, list, drawable, indexof

Having trouble using indexOf with a list of drawable resources. My index i is giving me a value of -1 (it's not finding the drawable resource).

```
Booster booster = new Booster();
Booster booster1 = booster.findBooster(R.drawable.booster_empty);

public Booster findBooster(int boosterID) {

    int[] boosterIDs = new int [] {
            R.drawable.booster_empty,
            R.drawable.booster_posts_1,
    };

    String[] names = new String[] {
            "blah",
            "blah"
    };

    String[] descriptions = new String[] {
            "blah",
            "blah"
    };

    String[] boosts = new String[] {
            "blah",
            "blah"
    };

    int i = Arrays.asList(boosterIDs).indexOf(boosterID);

    Booster booster = new Booster(boosterID, names[i], descriptions[i], boosts[i]);

    return booster;
}
```

I know it's probably something very simple that I'm missing. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling Arrays.asList() on a primitive array will result in a list with one element (which is the array), instead of your expected array to list conversion. Try changing the `int[]` into an `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `List.indexOf()` expects an object, but you passed an `int` instead, that is why, int is primitive data type, not an object, that is why it can't find what you want

Comment: The `int` gets autoboxed to `Integer`

Comment: Correct, but let's say, you pass in 1, it get autoboxed to an Integer object 1, but, the indexOf method expects the name of the object, not an index of the object, get it?

Comment: Nope. The OP is trying to create a `List<Integer>` (`List<int>` really, but there's no such thing), but ends up creating a `List<int[]>` (See Justin's answer). Searching from an `List<Integer>` would work as the OP expects when passed an `int`, as it's checked with `equals()`, but unfortunately the created list is of wrong type.

Comment: True, but indexOf method still expects the name of the object, but he passed in boosterId instead which is an int.

Comment: ...which gets autoboxed to an `Integer`, and gets checked with `equals()` against the items on the list. If it was a `List<Integer>`, the corresponding element *would* get found. Forget about "names", they don't exist at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList(...) method takes in all the array elements and return an instance of the List containing these each element. In your case, you have added 1 array(object) which is an single element. Thus, when you access any element greater than 0 it throws and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. See an code example below with Output.

```
        //Changed the code to illustrate the best without depending on the project.
        int[] boosterIDs = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        //Arrays.asList() return an List object which contains only 1 element of type int[]
        List<int[]> asList = Arrays.asList(boosterIDs);
        for (int j = 0; j < asList.size(); j++) {
            int[] item = asList.get(j);
            System.out.println("Loop = " + j + "length = " + item.length + " Contents...");
            for (int k = 0; k < item.length; k++) {
                System.out.print(item[k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Printing second loop");
        int[] secondBooterIds = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        //Arrays.asList() return an List object which contains only 2 elements of type int[]
        List<int[]> secondList = Arrays.asList(boosterIDs, secondBooterIds);
        for (int j = 0; j < secondList.size(); j++) {
            int[] item = secondList.get(j);
            System.out.println("Loop = " + j + "length = " + item.length + " Contents...");
            for (int k = 0; k < item.length; k++) {
                System.out.print(item[k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

### Output

```
Loop = 0length = 2 Contents...
1 2 
Printing second loop
Loop = 0length = 2 Contents...
1 2 
Loop = 1length = 2 Contents...
3 4
```